# Call a function after action from previous function is completed

Tags: typescript, cocoscreator

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
if (condition == 'true'){
    this.function1();
    this.function2();
}
```

function1() code:

```
function1(){
    this.node.getChildByName("spriteName").active = true;
    this.node.getChildByName("spriteName").runAction(cc.moveTo(0.1, x, y));
}
```

function2() code:

```
function2(){
    this.node.getChildByName("spriteName").active = false;
}
```

How can I ensure that function2 is called only after function1 has completed?
I have tried `cc.delayTime()` but it's not proper.

Comment: what does `runAction(...)` returns? Does it return a `Promise<T>`? If so, you can return that and you can use async/await. https://blog.logrocket.com/async-await-in-typescript/. Because if it's synchronous, function2() should not be called until function1() is finished.

Comment: @Earlee `runAction` returns `cc.Action` instance which is a built in class that can be found in `Cocos Creator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna assume that you're using `Cocos Creator 2.4`.

The action system is currently deprecated ([source](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/scripting/actions.html)). It might be wise to use [`cc.tween`](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/scripting/tween.html) instead.

## Solution using cc.tween (recommended)

You can use [`cc.tween`](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/scripting/tween.html) methods such as [`to`](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/api/en/classes/Tween.html#to) and [`call`](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/api/en/classes/Tween.html#call) to move your node and call a method.

### Example

Here's an example made using the code that you provided (in TypeScript).

```
const {ccclass, property} = cc._decorator;

@ccclass
export default class TestScript extends cc.Component
{
    private x: number = 15;
    private y: number = 15;

    start()
    {
        this.function1();
    }

    function1()
    {
        const sprite = this.node.getChildByName("spriteName");
        sprite.active = true;

        cc.tween(sprite)
            .to(1, { position: cc.v3(this.x, this.y, 0) })
            .call(() => this.function2())
            .start();
    }

    function2()
    {
        this.node.getChildByName("spriteName").active = false;
    }
}
```

## Solution using Action System (deprecated)

If you still wish to stay with your initial solution, you can call a method after an action is done by using [`cc.sequence`](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/api/en/modules/cc.html#sequence) and [`cc.callFunc`](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/api/en/modules/cc.html#callfunc). The first method will be used to call actions in sequence one by one and the other one will be used as an action that just calls a method.

### Example

Here's an another example made using the code that you provided (in TypeScript).

```
const {ccclass, property} = cc._decorator;

@ccclass
export default class TestScript extends cc.Component
{
    private x: number = 15;
    private y: number = 15;

    start()
    {
        this.function1();
    }

    function1()
    {
        const sprite = this.node.getChildByName("spriteName");
        sprite.active = true;

        const moveAndDisable = cc.sequence(
            cc.moveTo(1, this.x, this.y),
            cc.callFunc(() => this.function2()));
        
        sprite.runAction(moveAndDisable);
    }

    function2()
    {
        this.node.getChildByName("spriteName").active = false;
    }
}
```

---

## Extra solution - cc.tween + Promise

If you wish to move several objects simultaneously with various different durations but wish to run a method after all of them have finished moving, you can use [`cc.tween`](https://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/scripting/tween.html) in combination with [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) class.

### Example

```
const {ccclass, property} = cc._decorator;

@ccclass
export default class TestScript extends cc.Component
{
    @property(cc.Sprite)
    private sprite1: cc.Sprite = null;

    @property(cc.Sprite)
    private sprite2: cc.Sprite = null;

    @property(cc.Sprite)
    private sprite3: cc.Sprite = null;

    private x: number = 15;
    private y: number = 15;

    start()
    {
        this.function1();
    }

    function1()
    {
        Promise
            .all([
                this.moveNodeToPosition(this.sprite1.node, cc.v3(this.x, this.y, 0), 1.0),
                this.moveNodeToPosition(this.sprite2.node, cc.v3(this.x, this.y, 0), 1.5),
                this.moveNodeToPosition(this.sprite3.node, cc.v3(this.x, this.y, 0), 2.0),
            ])
            .then(this.function2);
    }

    function2()
    {
        cc.log("done");
    }

    moveNodeToPosition(
        target: cc.Node,
        position: cc.Vec3,
        duration: number) : Promise<unknown>
    {
        return new Promise(resolve =>
        {
            cc.tween(target)
                .to(duration, { position: position })
                .call(() => resolve(null))
                .start();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have to move 3 different sprite in function1() in that case how do I call function2()?

Comment: @KaverappaPH Well, assuming you want to move all 3 sprites simultaneously with different durations and then run your method after all of them have finished moving, [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method might be of use. I Updated the answer with an additional example.

Comment: @KaverappaPH If you intend to run them in sequence, one after another before running `function2`, [`Promise.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) might be of use.